# Xcode list of connected network shares lion / mountain lion

Tags: objective-c, xcode

is it possible to get a list of all connected network shares / remote volumnes in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YEs, take a look at [GETFSSTAT](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getfsstat.2.html) .

> getfsstat -- get list of all mounted file systems